# How can I add Point System to my Game (java)

Tags: java

I'm facing a little Problem here with my code , I want to add a points counter system , but I couldn't

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package rockpapercissor;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author almx9
 */
public class RockPaperCissor {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        int Player;
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many rounds do you want to play");
        int Rounds = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < Rounds ; i++)
        {
            
            
                int Computer = (int) (Math.random()*3)+1;
                System.out.println("Choose one:\n 1- Rock \n 2- Paper \n 3- Cissor");
                Player = input.nextInt();
                Check(Computer,Player);
                
                
                
            
        }
        System.out.println(" \nGame Finished thank you for playing... \n\n\n");
        
    }
    
    public static void Check (int C , int P )
    {
       
        /*
        1 = Rock
        2 = Paper
        3 = Cissor
        */
        if ((C == 1) && (P == 2))
        {
           
            System.out.println("Computer is Rock and you are Paper \nYou won!!\n");
           
        }
        if ((C == 1) && (P == 3))
        {
            
            System.out.println("Computer is Rock and you are Cissor \nYou Lost!!\n");
        }
        if ((C == 2) && (P == 1))
        {
            
            System.out.println("Computer is Paper and you are Rock \nYou Lost!!\n");
        }
        if ((C == 2) && (P == 3))
        {
            
            System.out.println("Computer is Paper and you are Cissor \nYou won!!\n");
        }
        if ((C == 3) && (P == 1))
        {
           
            System.out.println("Computer is Cissor and you are Rock \nYou won!!\n");
        }
        if ((C == 3) && (P == 2))
        {
            
            System.out.println("Computer is Cissor and you are Paper \nYou Lost!!\n");
        }
        if ((C == 1) && (P == 1))
        {
            System.out.println("Computer is Rock and you are Rock \nIt's a Draw!!\n");
        }
        if ((C == 2) && (P == 2))
        {
            System.out.println("Computer is Paper and you are Paper \nIt's a Draw!!\n");
        }
        if ((C == 3) && (P == 3))
        {
            System.out.println("Computer is Cissor and you are Cissor \nIt's a Draw!!\n");
        }
        
    }
    
   
}
```

how can I add a point system , like if the player is rock and computer is Cissor I want to show the Points , I tried to do it inside the if statment with

```
int PPoints = 0;
int CPoints = 0;
if ((C == 3) && (P == 1))
        {
            PPoints++;
            System.out.println("Computer is Cissor and you are Rock \nYou won!!\nPlayer Points:" + PPoints + "Computer Points:" + CPoints + "\n" );
        }
```

but it always return the value to 0 , i'm new to java and i'm still learning . thank you

Comment: Increment a counter for points outside of the topmost loop.  And assign points whenever either computer or human wins.

Comment: Java variables start with lowercase letters, `int Player;` is not good. It should be `int player;` Same goes for `int C , int P` and `int PPoints = 0; int CPoints = 0;`. Variables starting with capital letters are used for classes. Method names also start with lowercase letters.

Comment: You probably define the points in the wrong scope, like in that `Check` method. Define them in `main` and pass them to `Check`. This is just a guess, though, as your code doesn't show this important detail. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, I'll go through them one by one:

**1. Naming conventions**

I've already mentioned this in the comments:

> Java variables start with lowercase letters, int Player; is not good. It should be int player; Same goes for int C , int P and int PPoints = 0; int CPoints = 0;. Variables starting with capital letters are used for classes. Method names also start with lowercase letters. – Dropout 3 mins ago

Please refer to https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html

**2. use of conditional logic and the `check` method**

The method has several `if`s that even if triggered lead to other conditions being checked. In other words if your first condition is true, then why check other scenarios? This is much more efficient:

```
public static int check(int computer, int player) {
   
    /*
    1 = Rock
    2 = Paper
    3 = Cissor
    */

    if (computer == player) { //covers all draws
        System.out.println("It's a draw!");
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (computer == 1 && player == 2) { //R vs P
            System.out.println("Player wins!");
            return 2;
        } else if (computer == 1 && player == 3) { //R vs S
            System.out.println("Computer wins!");
            return 1;
        } else if (computer == 2 && player == 1) { //P vs R
            System.out.println("Computer wins!");
            return 1;
        } else if (computer == 2 && player == 3) { //P vs S
            System.out.println("Player wins!");
            return 2;
        } else if (computer == 3 && player == 2) { //S vs P
            System.out.println("Computer wins!");
            return 1;
        } else if (computer == 3 && player == 1) { //S vs R
            System.out.println("Player wins!");
            return 2;
        }
    }
    
    return -1;
}
```

Note that the method now returns an `int` which holds the info about which player won - 1 is player1, 2 is player2, 0 is a draw and -1 when something goes wrong, but that shouldn't happen. As soon as one condition is true the return inside it is called and it doesn't progress throughout the method further needlessly.

There are far better approaches to how to implement a RPS game, but for the sake of time and example let's go with this.

**3. finally implementing the scoring system**

You need to put the variables that hold the score outside of the cycling function, so that they don't get reset back to 0 every cycle. Then inside the cycles where you play the game you should increment them based on who wins

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int player;
    int cScore = 0; //<-- here
    int pScore = 0; //<-- here

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many rounds do you want to play");
    int rounds = input.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
        int computer = (int) (Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        System.out.println("Choose one:\n 1- Rock \n 2- Paper \n 3- Scissors");
        player = input.nextInt();

        int winner = check(computer, player);
        if (winner > 0) { //not a draw or an error
            if (winner == 1) { //computer won
                cScore++;
            } else { //player won
                pScore++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(String.format("Final score -\tCOMPUTER:%s\tPLAYER:%s",
            cScore,
            pScore
    ));
    System.out.println(" \nGame Finished thank you for playing... \n\n\n");
}
```